# Simplify 5|secθ| if θ=arcctan(x/5)

Tags: trigonometry

I got the answer wrong on a test so I was hoping if someone could help me correct it. I put the answer was 5secθ

Comment: Draw a right triangle with legs $x$ and 5. Work out the hypotenuse, and find your trig functions.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\implies\tan\theta=\dfrac x5$$

$$\sec^2\theta=1+\left(\dfrac x5\right)^2=\dfrac{x^2+25}{25}$$

Observe that $|\sec\theta|, \sqrt{x^2+25}>0$

Answer (score 2):

$\theta=\tan^{-1} \dfrac{x}{5} \Longrightarrow \tan \theta = \dfrac {x}{5}$
But, $\tan^2 \theta +1=\sec^2 \theta=\dfrac{x^2}{25}+1=\dfrac{x^2+25}{25}$

Hence, $5|\sec \theta|=\sqrt{x^2+25}$